# How do you compare a nullable int to an int

Tags: c#, compare, nullable, equality

In my Linq query I have the following :

```
.Where(x => x.dtt_ref_no == dtt_ref)
```

where **x.dtt_ref_no** is a **nullable int**
and **dtt_ref** is of type **int**.
What is the correct way to compare these two values?

Answer (score 9):

Your code works as it is, if you use `==` on a `int?` and an `int` it will return `false` if the nullable doesn't contain a value. So it's the same as if you'd write:

```
.Where(x => x.dtt_ref_no.HasValue &&  x.dtt_ref_no.Value == dtt_ref)
```

It's the same behaviour as [`Nullable<T>.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6(v=vs.110).aspx) because the `int` will be converted to an `int?` [implicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx) on comparison.

Comment: Oh crap.. my bad. I was running the linq query against the incorrect object. Thanks!

Comment: According to the IDE, "the `int` will be converted to an `int?`" is incorrect. It claims to convert the `int?` to `int` (hover on the `==`), although that makes it very obscure what causes false if the `int?` has no value!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Equals` overload:

```
.Where(x => x.dtt_ref_no.Equals(dtt_ref))
```